# cutting face at texture wrap

Tags: texturing, uv

i've been looking everywhere for this but i can't find anything at all... basically what i'm trying to do is something like

normal:

[image]
what i'm trying to do:

[image]
is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. Make a flat plane, and create UVs. 
   It should automatically adjust to the texture you have.
2. Duplicate it, and then move it to each side, so that you create that checker board pattern you want.
3. Then, you could simply create a cylinder and use it in a boolean operation to cut the flat planes into the circular shape you want. 
   You'll need to do some extra cleanup, but it should work.

Comment: that's not what i'm trying to do, im trying to cut the face itself into quads or whatever for every time the uv wrap hits the edge on each repeat, i used the circle texture just as an example but ye

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your starting case this way:
[image]
And applied this script:

```
import bpy, bmesh
from math import ceil

tolerance = 0.001  # increase to use more existing vertices close to the cuts

def main():
    me = bpy.context.active_object.data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
    uv_layer = bm.loops.layers.uv.verify()
    face = bm.faces[0]  # assuming there's just 1 face at the beginning
    # I'm also assuming the UV mapping respects aspect ratio and there's no stretching
    loop1, loop2 = face.loops[0], face.loops[1]
    x1, x2 = loop1.vert.co.x, loop2.vert.co.x
    uvx1, uvx2 = loop1[uv_layer].uv[0], loop2[uv_layer].uv[0]
    lenx, lenuvx = x2-x1, uvx2-uvx1
    ratio = lenx / lenuvx
    x_coords = sorted(v.co.x for v in face.verts)
    y_coords = sorted(v.co.y for v in face.verts)
    uvx_min, uvx_max = x_coords[0]/ratio -.5, x_coords[-1]/ratio -.5
    uvy_min, uvy_max = y_coords[0]/ratio -.5, y_coords[-1]/ratio -.5
    
    for uvx in range(ceil(uvx_min), ceil(uvx_max)):
        bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=[*bm.faces, *bm.edges], dist=tolerance,
            plane_co=((uvx+.5)*ratio, 0, 0), plane_no=(1, 0, 0))

    for uvy in range(ceil(uvy_min), ceil(uvy_max)):
        bmesh.ops.bisect_plane(bm, geom=[*bm.faces, *bm.edges], dist=tolerance,
            plane_co=(0, (uvy+.5)*ratio, 0), plane_no=(0, 1, 0))
        
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: a few improvements could be made, optimizations, as well as you could iterate over added vertices, and if they connect to 2 old vertices (so they are on the circumference) you could move them along the non-circumference edge to be the same distance away from the center as other vertices. 